# Can't get ui-view to inject template into parent state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I can't, for the life of me, get this darn thing to work.  stateTwo in the plunker below just will not inject into the parent state's controller.  What in the world am I doing wrong here??

http://plnkr.co/edit/N9wpkwJ8ByLW3w8W2T79

Comment: ok.. just checked the Network traffic.. it's actually _getting_ the sampleview.html template!  Why the heck isn't it injecting it into the ui-view div then???

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Could you explain more about it? By the way, I found a error in `views`: you typed `sampleView` without quotes.

Comment: @Jobsamuel: see the my answer.. naming convensions for views are apparently rather particular.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I just needed the naming convention 'sampleview@stateTwo' for my view config and it works.  I don't really know why 'sampleview@' didn't since the documentation seems to suggest that it *should*.

Anyway.. updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/N9wpkwJ8ByLW3w8W2T79?p=preview